# How to make the QTabWidget expandable with the form

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtabwidget

In QT Designer, I have a form into which I have added a QTabWidget.

But during preview, when I expand the form, the tab stays as it is.
How can I make the tab expand.

Is this a limitation of the QT designer and when i actually run it will the tab expand?

I have set the size policy as expandable for both x, y.
Is there anything else I should be doing to get this?

Answer (score 1):

You should add layout to the widget. Only if a widget has a layout, its contents will be moved and resized automatically when widget is resized.

To do this, you need to right-click on main widget in Designer and choose "Add layout -> Grid layout" (for example).